# allow native scroll in container during touchmove event like with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Is there a way to allow native scrolling easily without heavy JS modifications when you reach the border of a div via custom drag and drop via touchmove listener?
When you drag the text in the div [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g42fmxh1/) you'll see the div inside is scrolling automatically
[image]

I provided an [example with touchmove listeners](https://jsfiddle.net/c6khf93w/8/) but this one does not scroll, when you reach a border with your mouse
[image]

Is there an easy way to include a scrolling behavior to the 2nd example?

```js
const element = document.body.querySelector('#draggable');

const isInContainer = (x,y) => {
    const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y)
    return elements.find(el => el && el.classList && el.classList.contains('container')) || false;
}

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    if(isInContainer(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
        element.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        element.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }
}

const onMouseUp = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
}

element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp)
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement the functionality with native drag events? I'm not sure if that will help, though. The root cause is `position: absolute`, which takes the element out of the text-flow.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately our clients use older iPhones without native drag and drop functionality plus the software requires us to have a huge amount of elements. Native drag and drop has a terrible performance when it comes to tons of divs (it's a shift plan for a large company). My "current" solution was to show scroll arrows at the borders and set the scrollLeft/scrollTop of the container when the mouse is inside but the native scroll experience is far better than this custom solution

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has a native better solution I'm willing to accept that one... for the time being [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ndmaqr4z/12/) would be my current way to solve the issue.

Note: I made a custom interval for scrolling and don't use the `mousemove` event so users don't have to move the mouse to trigger it. moving outside will start the interval moving inside will clear it.

```
// the container that should scroll
const scrollBody = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');

// parameter to check which directions should scroll
const scrollPositions = {
  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  down: false,
}

// how far should be scrolled
const nextScrollDistance = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

// scroll interval
let scrollInterval= null;
const startScrolling = (scrollBody) => {
  if (scrollInterval !== null) {
    return true;
  }

  const intervalCallback = () => {
    if (scrollInterval !== null && nextScrollDistance.x === 0 && nextScrollDistance.y === 0) {
      window.clearInterval(scrollInterval);
      scrollInterval = null;
    } else {
      scrollBody.scrollLeft += nextScrollDistance.x;
      scrollBody.scrollTop += nextScrollDistance.y;
    }
  }

  scrollInterval = window.setInterval(intervalCallback, 50);
}

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  if(isInContainer(e.pageX, e.pageY)){
    element.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    element.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  }
  
  const rects = scrollBody.getBoundingClientRect();
  // check directions

  // max x that can be scrolled
  const maxX = scrollBody.scrollWidth - scrollBody.clientWidth;
  // max y that can be scrolled
  const maxY = scrollBody.scrollHeight - scrollBody.clientHeight;

  // check all directions if it's even possible to scroll
  const canScrollTop = Math.round(scrollBody.scrollTop) > 0;
  const canScrollBottom = Math.round(scrollBody.scrollTop) < maxY;
  const canScrollLeft = Math.round(scrollBody.scrollLeft) > 0;
  const canScrollRight = Math.round(scrollBody.scrollLeft) < maxX;

  // current x and y coordinates of the mouse
  const x = e.pageX;
  const y = e.pageY;

  // dynamic value to decrease the speed.. otherwise it might scroll too fast
  const minifier = 2;

  // the modifiers for scrollTop and scrollLeft
  nextScrollDistance.y = 0;
  nextScrollDistance.x = 0;

  if (canScrollBottom && y > rects.bottom) {
    // distance between the right border and the mouse
    const distance = Math.abs(y - rects.bottom);

    // the next time it scrolls -> scroll distance / minifier
    nextScrollDistance.y = Math.round(distance / minifier)
    scrollPositions.down = true;
  } else {
    scrollPositions.down = false;
  }

  // all other directions...
  if (canScrollTop && y < rects.top) {
    const distance = Math.abs(y - rects.top);
    nextScrollDistance.y = Math.round(distance / minifier) * -1;
    scrollPositions.up = true;
  } else {
    scrollPositions.up = false;
  }

  if (canScrollRight && x > rects.right) {
    const distance = Math.abs(x - rects.right);
    nextScrollDistance.x = Math.round(distance / minifier)
    scrollPositions.right = true;
  } else {
    scrollPositions.right = false;
  }

  if (canScrollLeft && x < rects.left) {
    const distance = Math.abs(x - rects.left);
    nextScrollDistance.x = Math.round(distance / minifier) * -1;
    scrollPositions.left = true;
  } else {
    scrollPositions.left = false;
  }

  // in case one of those are set.. trigger scrolling
  if (nextScrollDistance.x || nextScrollDistance.y) {
    startScrolling();
  }
  
}
```